# SMTP Connection fails with TLS activated

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer, starttls

I am using the PHPMailer to send E-Mails to my customers. I want to send them using SSL/TLS, but this doesn't work. I am using an original example script from PHPMailer. When I comment this line: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and change the credentials to my non ssl SMTP it works fine. Otherwise I get this error:

"Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed."

I googled already and found similar problems where uncommenting `;extension=php_openssl.dll` this line in the php.ini helped. But uncommenting this doesn't help me and I checked with phpinfo() that openssl is already enabled, so it should work or ? This is what I see at my phpinfo(): http://puu.sh/fyg5Z/a1ab5b0ea5.png

**My used example (ofc with my own smtp credentials):**

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

How can I fix it? I tested the SMTP TLS connection with my email client thunderbird, which worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure on the port? TLS SMTP should use 465. 587 is the port for unencrypted submissions.

Comment: As I said I use ofcourse my right credentials and there i use the port 465. Thats not the problem here for sure. Tho I edited into the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the closed issues section of the phpmailer github. I will quote the developer Synchro:

> You can't use ssl with port 587. The only combinations that will work
>   are tls/587 and ssl/465, but you should use TLS. It doesn't make any
>   differnce if you site uses http or https.

Comment: Fame at last! Thanks!

Comment: Lol how did you find that so fast :( :D. Keep that work up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send email with php tls/ssl stram socket (this example using STARTTLS command to start tls/ssl connection to smtp server). It is very simple, you need only create mime message here example https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser/blob/master/PhpMimeClient_class.php with attachments and inline images:

```
<?php
// Login email and password
$login = "your-email@cool.xx";
$pass = "123456";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer_name', false);
try{
    // echo $socket = stream_socket_client('ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    echo $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if (!$socket) {
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
        return;
    }else{
        // Http
        // fwrite($socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
        // Smtp
        echo fread($socket,8192);
        echo fwrite($socket, "EHLO cool.xx\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        // Start tls connection
        echo fwrite($socket, "STARTTLS\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);

        // Send ehlo
        echo fwrite($socket, "EHLO cool.xx\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        // echo fwrite($socket, "MAIL FROM: <hello@cool.com>\r\n");
        // echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, base64_encode($login)."\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, base64_encode($pass)."\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "rcpt to: <to-email@boome.com>\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "DATA\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "Date: ".time()."\r\nTo: <to-email@boome.com>\r\nFrom:<zour-email@cool.xx\r\nSubject:Hello from php socket tls\r\n.\r\n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        echo fwrite($socket, "QUIT \n");
        echo fread($socket,8192);

        /* Turn off encryption for the rest */
        // stream_socket_enable_crypto($fp, false);

        fclose($socket);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using port 465 for SMTPS (Encrypted SMTP)

See:

https://www.fastmail.com/help/technical/ssltlsstarttls.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: ...which has been deprecated since 1998

Answer (score -1):

Disable SMTP TLS in `Pear::mail`

Edit the file in below mentioned path.

```
/opt/lampp/lib/php/Net_SMTP/Net/SMTP.php
```

Find the line with the following content,

```
function auth($uid, $pwd, $method = '', $tls = true, $authz = '')
```

Replace this with:

`function auth($uid, $pwd, $method = '', $tls = false, $authz = '')`